# Top Down Recursive Parsing

Tags: f#

I need to include function parseS, parseL, and parseE. These functions will take as input an already tokenized ‘program’ represented as a list of tokens.

```
type token = TK_IF | TK_THEN | TK_ELSE | TK_BEGIN | TK_END | TK_PRINT | TK_SEMIC | TK_ID of string;;


let program = [ TK_IF; TK_ID("a"); TK_THEN; TK_BEGIN; TK_PRINT; TK_ID("b"); TK_SEMIC; TK_PRINT; TK_ID("c");  TK_END; TK_ELSE; TK_PRINT; TK_ID("d")];;
```

and output something like this:

```
parseS program;;
IF2(ID "a",STATLIST(PRINT (ID "b"),LISTCONT(PRINT (ID "c"),END)),PRINT (ID "d"))
```

The parseL should look something like this

```
let rec parseL = function
 | TK_END::xs -> (xs,END)
 | TK_SEMIC::xs -> let (rest,stat) = parseS xs
                   let (rest,lst) = parseL rest
                   (rest, LISTCONT(stat,lst))
 | l -> failwith ("error parsing L (expecting TK_END or TK_SEMIC):" + (List.map debug l).ToString())
```

Help?

Comment: As you are new to StackOverflow it is frowned upon to ask for someone to do work that you should be doing. Also this appears to be a homework problem as you gave a specific format for the answer. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Then read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see where your specific problem is and then help you. As such I am giving this a close vote.

Comment: I'm relatively new here, so let's wait for others with more experience to chime in.  It feels to me like you're asking for us to do something for you without telling us 1) what you have already tried, and 2) why it didn't work for you.  Please emphasize these things, and you'll probably get more assistance.  As to your question, take a quick glance at FParsec, or other similar tools -- they're designed for this exact case and will help you take your first steps.  Even if you choose not to use them, they will help you understand the task at hand.

Comment: @chryosolo While I do agree that [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) is the obvious way to solve this, based on the skill level of the OP I think that jumping into FParsec without going through the basics of parser combinators will be intimidating.

Comment: I been trying to work at it but nothing is engendering

Comment: @guyCoder, I've enjoyed reading your questions and answers - you have a lot of interesting things to say, and I know I'll learn a lot from your wisdom.  As this is probably homework, I didn't feel like it was my job lay out a meaningful path for the OP to follow, instead giving the end goal for future readers who come across the question, at least they'll have a link to the target.  However, I yield to your greater SO experience -- I see you took the path of pointing out links on how to ask better questions - I'll do the same in the future.

Comment: @chryosolo Nice of you to point out for FParsec for others that come here trying to understand parsing with functions. :)

Comment: @Pringles We all learn from our mistakes and the mistakes of others, that is one of the reasons I like SO is so that I can learn from others and they can learn from my mistakes. Just post what you have tried, no matter how bad you may think it is, and then we can get you started in the right direction. I suspect that your code is not more than a page, is so post it all.

Comment: @Pringles Most likely what will happen is that you will not get answer until you post a specific problem that we can reproduce or at least understand where you need help. If someone does give you a complete answer, then have you really learned? Did you get a fish or learn how to fish?

Comment: @Pringles Where did you get this from, after reviewing the code in detail I see the `debug function` in `(List.map debug l).` which I suspect was given to you since adding debugging to functional parsing is not one of the basics, but usually introduced after lexing, parsing and printing, and then usually after doing a few concrete examples.

Comment: This is duplicate, but the earlier question was deleted on SO but recorded [here](http://quabr.com/29062329/f-writing-a-recursive-descent-parser-for-a-grammar)